# How to write a query to check if a column value is in a PHP array that may be empty

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to return records where a id field is in a php array. Usually I would do something like this:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4)
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE statusId IN (" . implode(',',$ids) . ")";
```

However, if the `$ids` array happens to be empty, I get a error from mysql because of the empty parentheses. I can accomplish my goal using a subquery like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE statusId IN (SELECT statusId FROM statuses WHERE /* some conditions */)";
```

If the subquery is empty, then it will just return an empty record set without an error. I don't want to use the subquery because I already have the ids in the php variable.

Is there a way to write the first query so it doesn't return an error if the php array is empty? I know I can just write a conditional statement and just not run the query if the php array is empty. But for style reasons, I just want to see if there is a way to write the query that returns a empty set if the php array is empty.

Comment: Why don't you check the array first, and run your query if it is not?

Comment: `in(null,etc....)` would be safest. `null` can't be tested for in `in`, since `in` does equality tests, and null can't be equal to anything, including itself.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I was just curious if there is a way without checking the array first. I was thinking it would make the code look cleaner.

Comment: @Andrew makes sense, It seems like anything else would require you to make a trip to the database, and just have an empty resultset. Checking the array would avoid that db trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would better check if the array is empty. Just write:

```
if ( empty($ids) ) { 
   //Don't run query
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is probably the right way to do it. However I was actually hoping there was a way to do it without checking the array first.

Comment: Well, by checking the array first you don't need to run a db query, which means your app will have a better performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4)
$idClause = !empty($ids) ? implode(',',$ids) : 'NULL';
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE statusId IN (" . $idClause . ")";
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that there would be a way to do it with MySQL code but now that I think about it, I guess mysql can't actually see the php array so this is probably the closest to what I was thinking.

Comment: @Andrew, as you know, we can't pass PHP array to a DB query. We should make it compatible with the queries. However, there are many ways to achieve your goals. You could pick one and don't be too worried about the performance. It's not a high volume query

Answer (score 0):

try doing a ternary

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4)

$query = !empty($ids) ? "SELECT * FROM table WHERE statusId IN (" . implode(',',$ids) . ")" : "SELECT * FROM table WHERE statusId IN (SELECT statusId FROM statuses WHERE /* some conditions */)";
```

;